# Send file attachment with SendGrid PHP (sendgrid-php library)

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, sendgrid

When I try to send an attachment using the SendGrid PHP library (https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php), the function fails (white screen).  Removing the "setAttachment" line makes it work again.

Here is my code:

```
require "sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php";
function sendgrid() {

   $recips = array("me@mydomain.ca");
   $categories = array("test");



   $sendgrid = new SendGrid("API key removed");

   $email = new SendGrid\Email();
   $email
   ->setSmtpapiTos($recips)
   ->setFrom('mailroom@mydomain.ca')
   ->setSubject('Testing Sendgrid')
   ->setText('Hello World! Testing...')
   ->setHtml('<strong>Hello World!</strong>')
   ->setCategories($categories)
   ->setAttachment('test.txt')
   ;


   //$sendgrid->send($email);

   $res = $sendgrid->send($email);

   var_dump($res);
}

sendgrid();
```

As far as I can tell, I'm following the documentation, but I wonder if I haven't formatted the path to the file correctly.  "Test.txt" is in the same directory as the file that contains the above code.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
 ->setAttachment(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'test.txt');
```

Comment: Incredible, it worked! Thank you!  I wonder if this is something that should be in the documentation, or if it's just something peculiar to my environment?

Comment: You need to use the absolute filepath, i am presuming that class file most likely looked for the file relative to its path. Since it couldnt find it it failed, but  by providing the absolute filepath it knew where exactly to look

Comment: if you want open sendgrid-php.php file and try and look for the method and see what it does :) its the best way you will learn forward

Comment: Do you know how to send attachments(unique attachment with each email) with setSmtpapiTos while sending bulk emails

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't really belong here but as of April 17th 2019 SendGrid broke their `postfix` mechanism and enforced v3 PHP client without "proper" documentation. And I mean: nothing is properly documented so (since this post came up top of google when I typed in SendGrid - here goes)

so if you see this.. do not panic this post will help u

```
invalid authentication method - declined because you are using basic authentication with 2FA enabled. to fix, update to using an API key or disable 2FA and switch to using IP Access Management for security.
```

**Some problems with the docs**

SendGrids docs on v3 are (in my opinion)

- declarative rather than informative (a functional declaration rather than technical information)
- cripplingly wrong (wild goose chase of circular links)
- out of date (with nothing to alert you)
- missing essential components (so won't work out of the box with no hint as to why) ....

for example : (just a flavour) here we see "**they**" (SendGrid) simply took out **\SendGrid\Email()** and replaced it with **\SendGrid\Mail\Mail()** in their code base but didn't update their docs - so their posted examples will not work. - it's very minor as a change - but as written the callers are different and they never updated their examples.. with everything else they omitted it is making very hard work of a easy thing.

**i.e. THIS EXAMPLE WORKS v3**

```
    $sendgrid = new SendGrid("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
    $email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
    $email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
    $email->addTo("bigman@getme.com", "Example User");
    $email->addContent(
        "text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP"
    );
    $email->addContent(
        "text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
    );

    //optional (seems to be bullet proof, pdf,  png, etc) to attach a file<START>
    $att1 = new \SendGrid\Mail\Attachment();
    $att1->setContent(file_get_contents("/path/to/some/test_attach.txt"));
    $att1->setType("application/octet-stream");
    $att1->setFilename(basename("/path/to/some/test_attach.txt"));
    $att1->setDisposition("attachment");
    $email->addAttachment($att1);
    //optional to attach a file</END>       

    try {
        $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
        print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
        print_r($response->headers());
        print $response->body() . "\n";
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }`
```

**TO UPGRADE TO v3 SEND GRID PHP CLIENT without composer on PHP 5.6**

if you're like me and hate composer (don't even get me started) THE GOOD NEWS IS you ***can*** get SendGrid to work so- just so you know .. almost everything "**they**" (SendGrid) direct you to online is going to struggle to help you

After April 17th 2019 SendGrid said you NEED to use v3 **YOU WILL NEED PHP 5.6.** (rightly or wrongly PHP 5.4 is the ceiling of redhat/centos at time of writing) and  **YOU CANNOT USE postfix** anymore (despite them never specifically saying this nor labeling their postfix examples v2 max, i.e. disabled as of 17th April 2019)

So as of 17th April 2019

```
-> you have to use v3 
-> you have to use the PHP client... (no postfix)
-> you have to upgrade to 5.6 
-> you **DO NOT** have to use composer (but if you don't you need to pay attention, see below)
```

**ALSO -> (IMPORTANT) you are stuck with the client or the curl at v3** (they don't simply *say* this) no postfix. forget it. also re: the Curl mechanism (while it does work with 5.4) carries a) no documentation on using  attachments AND b) utilizes illegal json_encoding  PHP cannot output ( PHP cannot give "{[{}]}" it's always "{"0":[{}]}")

but regardless not only MUST you use the SendGrid PHP client at 5.6 PHP (again no, server postfix option) *you still need to know you need TWO projects:* "[php-http-client-master](https://github.com/sendgrid/php-http-client)" and "[sendgrid-php-master](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php)" (BOTH repos) and this is undocumented: then you need to do the following: and the `/lib/loader.php` in "sendgrid-php-master" needs these two lines adding at the end

```
               require_once '/your/path/to/php-http-client-master/lib/Client.php';
               require_once '/your/path/to/php-http-client-master/lib/Response.php';
```

you also need to add this (sadly more sloppiness from SendGrid)

```
             require_once __DIR__ . '/mail/TypeException.php';
```

Incidentally I also edited `sendgrid-php-master\sendgrid-php.php` to this

```
          <? php
             require __DIR__ . '/lib/loader.php';
          ?>
```

theoretically adding composer would mean you could probably avoid all this but for some servers this is out of the question (implementing composer on a  different branch of my PHP project took 3 weeks - I am not repeating this) since composer introduces a breaking change in the way PHP handles includes and class autoloading

**PS: I have alerted SendGrid to all of this you may well find that this is cleared up pretty fast**